# After the events of 'The Big Bang' what is the state of Gallifrey?

Tags: doctor-who

After the events of episode 'The Big Bang', the Doctor has 'rebooted' the universe and is only brought back by Amy remembering him. It seems that those that were with him during those events retained their memories of the previous incarnation of the universe, but technically none of it ever happened.

As the Doctor himself says in 'A Good Man Goes to War', Amy and Rory's first time in the TARDIS in this universe was on their wedding night. So everything that happened previously is just a memory, just a story.

This question is kind of hinted at in other questions/answers, but I thought I'd ask it directly.

I can't remember exactly how he stated it, but before the new universe, when he is traveling back through his own time he says he has to step out of time, or remove himself from the universe, something like that.

How does that work? I guess you could call timey-wimey on him not being born in the universe, but then what happens to all of his past exploits? And what about his part in the time-war? Does all of that come back in some capacity when Amy pulls him back into the universe? How that would exclude events with Amy and Rory... well I have a headache now.

Comment: there was an entire planet removed from existance, where the House or whatever it was called would lure in and chop up Time Lords. And take their TARDISes

Answer (score 5):

In this scenario, being removed from reality does not exactly wipes you from existence, it just *pulls* you out from the Universe, like if you never existed. But all the events you did, everything you were involved in, happened, but just without you. This, of course, makes no sense per se, but it *explains* how can you exactly bring someone back *just* by remembering.

If it truly wiped you from existence, as if you never existed, all the decision you were involved in would be *rewritten* too, making a totally different reality.
Think of it this way, how would Amelia be alive if her parents never existed?

So, although The Doctor was *pulled out* from reality, all of his feats remained.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that angle, her parents being removed but her still being alive. But I'm pretty sure the Doctor actually says that anyone absorbed by it will be removed as if they were never born. Maybe it's by virtue of having grown up with the crack in the wall and traveling with the Doctor that makes her somewhat of a complicated space-time event, somewhat like the Doctor, minus the time-lord and about 900 years of shenanigans.

Comment: A common plot device in many sci-fi films is that those at the centre of something which destroyed the world/universe are somehow protected from the immediate consequences. A parallel in real life is the Hiroshima Memorial Building which survived to some degree because the explosion was directly above it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiroshima_Peace_Memorial

Answer (score 0):

Remember, the universe could only be rebooted because of Amy's memories. She absorbed everything up to the point that she left with the doctor, the night before her wedding from the crack in her wall.

She 'remembers' everything that happened previous to that night including the doctor and his shenanigans.

However the doctor takes himself out of the universe, overriding Amy's memories, causing her to consciously forget him. But, because of the clever passage the doctor says to amy as she sleeps, she ends up remembering him anyway, overriding his removal from the university, bringing him back into the galaxy.

Answer (score 0):

> As the Doctor himself says in 'A Good Man Goes to War', Amy and Rory's first time in the TARDIS in this universe was on their wedding night. So everything that happened previously is just a memory, just a story.

That's not right.

In fact, it's because they honestly spent very little time in the TARDIS together through season one. The Doctor lists the reasons in the same scene.